# Probability that $ABu=Cu$ for matrices in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ be three $n\times n$ matrices in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and let $u\in\{0,1\}^n$ uniformly choosen.

Can we find the probability of  $$P(ABu=Cu)\;?$$

Or just a bound, we have $ABu=Cu\Leftrightarrow Du=0$ where $D=AB-C$ so $$Du=0\rightarrow u_1=\frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1,j}u_{j}}{d_{1,1}}.$$ Then,
$$P(ABu=Cu)\le P\left(u_1= \frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1,j}u_{j}}{d_{1,1}}\right).$$

And perhaps there is a conditional argument ?

---

**Motivation of the problem** how can one decide that $AB=C.$

Comment: I've removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag. Please read the tag summary when using a tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Du=0$ defines a linear subspace $V$ of $\{0,1\}^n$ with dimension $\dim V=n-\operatorname{rank}D$. The probability of $Du=0$ for uniformly chosen $u$ is $2^{\dim V-n}=2^{-\operatorname{rank}D}$.